# How to run SNPEff jar for a batch of VCF files using GNU parallel tool?

Tags: java, bioinformatics, gnu, gnu-parallel, vcf-variant-call-format

How to run SNPEff jar for a batch of VCF files (300 items) using GNU parallel tool? Need a code example. Found only one example somehow similar to my question [.s.GNU parallel, execution of commands from file few at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072857/s-gnu-parallel-execution-of-commands-from-file-few-at-a-time). Thx.

Comment: There are many examples in the GNU-parallel doc. what have you tried ?

Comment: Show us how you run 10 items now (without GNU Parallel), and we can probably show you how to do it with GNU Parallel.